# 3D Drawing from a file in an extra directory

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, 3d

I want to put my txt files in an extra directory or folders. The txt file is data with 3 coloums. Then, I wish to draw a 3D diagram from this files. Codes are written in such a way that , I can randomly change that txt file without changing my code anymore. So the code looks like the following:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from os import listdir

def test(datei):
   return datei.endswith('.txt')

def xyz_ret(file):
    f = open(file, 'r')

    xyz = []
    for i in f:
        ret = i.replace('\n','')
        xyz.append(map(float,(ret.split('\t'))))

    xyz =  np.array(xyz)   
    return xyz[:,0],xyz[:,1],xyz[:,2]    

files=listdir("data")
files=filter(test, files) 
files.sort() 

x,y,z = xyz_ret(files)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

xi = np.linspace(min(x), max(x))
yi = np.linspace(min(y), max(y))

X, Y = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
Z = griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi)

surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=6, cstride=6, cmap=cm.jet,
        linewidth=0)

ax.set_zlim3d(min(z), max(z))

ax.w_zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))

fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)

plt.show()
```

However, I get an error:

```
C:\Users\penang\Desktop\3D drawing\test5>python test5.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test5.py", line 28, in <module>
    x,y,z = xyz_ret(files)
  File "test5.py", line 13, in xyz_ret
    f = open(file, 'r')
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: If `files` is a list of filenames, this list cannot be opened as file. Would you like to open each of those files? Or only the first one?

Comment: There is  only one file in the directory

Comment: Can you please post the full Error trace?

Comment: C:\Users\penang\Desktop\3D drawing\test5>python test5.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test5.py", line 28, in <module>
    x,y,z = xyz_ret(files)
  File "test5.py", line 13, in xyz_ret
    f = open(file, 'r')
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found

Comment: So you have a list with one entry, namely the one filename, e.g. `["myfile.txt"]`. But you cannot open a list, `open(["myfile.txt"])` does not make sense. Instead you need `open("myfile.txt")`.

Comment: This is not a matplotlib problem, so you should remove that tag. Otherwise, @ImportanceOfBeingErnest is right. Instead of `x,y,z = xyz_ret(files)`, try `x,y,z = xyz_ret(files[0])`.